# How to join two IQueryable list?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get the value by left join the result value of group by each.

```
        var mgga = mggb.GroupBy(i => i.GoodsCode).Select(i => i.MaxBy(x => x.PriceChangeDate));
        var oega = oegb.GroupBy(i => i.GoodsCode).Select(i => i.MinBy(x => x.EventSalePrice));
```

And join like this,

```
        var result = from mgg in mgga
                        join oeg in oega
                        on new { storeCode = mgg.StoreCode, goodsCode = mgg.GoodsCode } equals new { storeCode = oeg.StoreCode, goodsCode = oeg.GoodsCode } into mgoe
                        from oeg in mgoe.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new {
                            GoodsCode = mgg.GoodsCode,
                        };
```

But, this show error message.

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'g
          .AsQueryable()
          .Select(e => new {
              ...
           })
          .AsQueryable()
          .MaxBy(x => x.PriceChangeDate)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

How do I join mgga or oga with type IQueryable<'a>?

Comment: An IQueryable is a *query*, not a list. It contains no data. What are you trying to do? The error comes from EF, not LINQ. EF is an ORM - its job is to Map Objects to Relational data, not a way to write embedded SQL.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It contains no data, I convet by ToList() function and join?
mggb.ToList();
oegb.ToList();

Comment: No, you explain what you want to do. There's no `MinBy` in SQL. If you wanted to retrieve the minimum and maximum value of a field per group you'd write `.Select(g=> new {Key=g.Key,Max=g.Max(r=>SomeField), Min=g.Min(r=>r.SomeField)})`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you. First of all, I'm going to leave join the values of [A] where PriceChangeDate is Max in mmgb and [B] where EventSalePrice is minimum in oegb with GoodsCode in storeCode and goodsCode.

Comment: You're still describing the attempted solution, not the real problem. You shouldn't need any joins if you want to find the max date and min price in a group. The price on the latest date isn't a MIN/MAX operation, it's an `OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date).Take(1).Price`. Are you trying to find the minimum price in the latest date? That requires a subquery, not a join

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm sorry for the lack of explanation. mgga is product related information, and oga has event related information. This is the part to check whether there is event information for each product. That's why I'm doing mgga left join oega, and before joining each other, I'm trying to join by extracting the max value in mgga and min value in oga.

Comment: Post the code and tables, don't describe them. Besides, EF deals with **entities((, not tables. You should have a DbContext with Products and Events DbSets. A Product should have an Event or Events property. Same for `Event` - it should have a `Product` or `Products` property. It's EF's job to generate the proper JOINS from the entities. And you still haven't explained what you try to do. Display the latest price per product? The price of all products on the latest date? `ctx.Events.OrderByDescending(e=>e.Date).Take(1).Products.Select(p=>p.Price)`

Comment: Which version of EF Core?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv version is 6.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Okay, After organizing my thoughts, I think I need to look at the code one more time. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following implementation of your queries. Other part should work.

```cs
var mgga = mggb.GroupBy(i => i.GoodsCode)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.PriceChangeDate).First());
var oega = oegb.GroupBy(i => i.GoodsCode)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.EventSalePrice).First());
```